# JQuery - How to run an inline script referencing element by ID?

Tags: jquery

I have an onclick call on element. Can I run it by referencing the element by id?

```
<div onclick="random_function(with_a_lot_of_parameters)" id="this_element_id">...</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#this_element_id').click(function(event){ 
    //Do something
});
```

Will work, but if you want to access the div element through the inline call, you can pass the `this` keyword as a parameter to your function like:

```
<div onclick="random_function(this, a_lot_of_parameters)" id="this_element_id">...</div>
```

And then process it in your function:

```
random_function(element, param1, param2){
    alert(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just get the element and then call `click`

```
$('#this_element_id').click();
```

`$('#id')` takes the the id of the element in the form of a string and then returns the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a click handler using jquery and pass the function call, see below code

```
$(function(){
  $('#this_element_id').click(random_function());
}):
```

[For more information on Click Handler in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

Use onClientClick() for calling jquery function